# Android SDK and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I had my Eclipse and SDK set up. I just updated my SDK to the latest version with the latest platforms. When i try to run the AVD from ECLIPSE i get the following error message

[image]

When i go to Preferences and set the path for my SDK i get the following error message

[image]

When i browsed thru the SDK folder i found that the adb.exe file has been moved out of tools folder into the platforms-tools folder

[image]

How to i now tell Eclipse that abd.exe is in platform-tools folder not in tools folder ?

Tools Folder

[image]

Comment: please open tools not platform tool and show screen short

Comment: do you have delete manually any folder?

Comment: @Nik no i didnt touch anything.. link: http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2011-09-08_1155.png

Comment: `_UpgradeReport_Files` folder are also missing

Comment: please delete android sdk and install again

Comment: Copy adb.exe file in tools folder in android sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_UpgradeReport_Files` folder are also missing
`dmtracedump` is missing

**so you need to re-install your android-sdk

update with all avd

then  set path of avd in preference**

Answer (score 1):

if you've just updated your ADT then most likely whitespaces is the problem. No one knows how this creeps into the system while updating. Just move your entire android folder to "C:\" now goto the same point where you found the android preferences & set the path to C:\android\

now your good to go...happy coding !!

Comment: still it says adb is not found it tools folder

Comment: I hope you moved it from the android-sdk folder to c:\android-sdk...and set the path correctly...after update whitespaces become evident in windows based system

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete existing android sdk dir
2. Download new android sdk.
3. now from eclipse -> update -> ADTs then use it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try to update ADT. Starting from some andoid sdk version ( I believe it's 2.2) some command line android tools moved from tools to platform-tools folder. Newer versions of ADT reflect that change.